# java: cannot access scala.Serializable class file for scala.Serializable not found

Tags: java, scala, akka-stream, amazon-kinesis

In my Java project, I am trying to add a Java kinesis akka stream as Source by following [this](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/0.17/kinesis.html) link but he project fails to compile;

```
    Error:(22, 53) java: cannot access scala.Serializable
      class file for scala.Serializable not found
```

on this line `ShardSettings.create`

```
    final ShardSettings settings = ShardSettings.create("test-stream", "shard-id")
            .withShardIteratorType(ShardIteratorType.LATEST)
            .withRefreshInterval(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .withLimit(500);
```

I tried adding scala lang-library into my build.gradle, but no luck. Here is my build.gradle file;

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'scala'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.10'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-stream_2.13', version: '2.6.1'
    compile group: 'com.lightbend.akka', name: 'akka-stream-alpakka-kinesis_2.12', version: '0.17'
    compile group: 'com.lightbend.akka', name: 'akka-stream-alpakka-s3_2.12', version: '1.1.2'
}
```

Anyone has any clues what's going wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure the class scala.Serializable is in one of your dependendy library?

Comment: You can't have both `_2.13` and `_2.12` dependencies at once. Either fix `akka-stream` to some `_2.12` version (just removing it should be enough because it will be a dependency of `akka-stream-alpakka`), or all others to `_2.13` (and `scala-library`'s version).

Comment: Changing `akka-stream` version down to 12 fixed the problem. Thanks @Alexey :)